# Issue with drawing bitmap from URL

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I am relatively new to Java and Blackberry development so I am struggling a little..
I'm trying to load and display an image from a URL on the screen, here is the code I'm using to get the image:

```
public static Bitmap connectServerForImage(String url) {
HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
DataOutputStream httpDataOutput = null;
InputStream httpInput = null;
int rc;
Bitmap bitmp = null;
try {
httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/bd/AA_Reckless_%26_Relentless.jpg/220px-AA_Reckless_%26_Relentless.jpg");
rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
}
httpInput = httpConnection.openInputStream();
InputStream inp = httpInput;
byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
return hai.getBitmap();
} catch (Exception ex) {
System.out.println("URL Bitmap Error........" + ex.getMessage());
} finally {
try {
if (httpInput != null)
httpInput.close();
if (httpDataOutput != null)
httpDataOutput.close();
if (httpConnection != null)
httpConnection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
return bitmp;   


g.drawBitmap(250, 120, 150, 150, bitmp, 0, 0);
```

The problem I'm having is with the "g.drawBitmap(250, 120, 150, 150, bitmp, 0, 0);" Is there anything I should import or something like that?

How exactly do I draw/add the image to the screen.. I know I'm missing something obvious but I don't know what it is? Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code.  It's not readable without indentation.  I can't tell if `g.drawBitmap()` is being called from within the `connectServerForImage()` method, or outside of it.  What is your problem ... a **compile** error, or a **runtime** exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your biggest issue is you're not using an IDE. Eclipse is really nice for this. It'll tell you about imports, auto-indent, highlight errors etc.

That said, from what i can see g.drawBitmap is called incorrectly. g refers to a graphics object, which you get from overriding a *paint* method.

I don't know where you are trying to draw this but you basically have 2 options.

1. use **BitmapField**, its probably the best.
2. override the paint method of a field, and draw using drawBitmap.

A link for **BitmapField** hope it helps.
http://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/picture_bitmap_1984826_11.html

Comment: It's just the "g" part of "g.drawBitmap(150, 250, 250, 250, bitmp, 0, 0);" That gives an error. Error is "g cannot be resolved", and there is also no option to import anything from the Blackberry JDE.. What could be the problem?

Comment: The "g" refers to a Graphics object. If you haven't declared it, you'll get that error.

You can either override the paint method of a field, or screen to draw there. Or you can use the get getGraphics() method.

`getGraphics().drawBitmap(150, 250, 250, 250, bitmp, 0, 0);`